# foreach in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I know that foreach in nodejs is blocking. 
I am developing a API Server in nodejs and I need to parse through req.body to produce some kind of signature to validate request. So my question is if I use forEach on req.body will it block other request? How to overcome it if it is blocking?

Comment: What libraries are you using? What does your code look like? Node.js properly developed shouldn't block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

forEach is blocking, but for most use cases it's just fine, so long as your array.length * function.runTime isn't very large, which it shouldn't be unless you're doing IO or crypto.  If you are doing something with a long run time you can then replace the forEach with an async.forEach (https://github.com/caolan/async)

Comment: hello, I have considered using async. is it ok to use async even if the array is not very large? generally I will be just looping to posts fields in request.

Comment: Using async isn't really about the length, it's about the runTime.  What are you doing in your `forEach(function` ?

Comment: What i am trying to do is go through each post field and append them and generate hmac signature. Am i doing it right?

Comment: I think so, alternatively you can use `require('child_process').fork` to create a worker process to send the job to if performance becomes a real issue.

Comment: won't using async.forEach be non blocking ?

Comment: Kind of, it will let other requests through the cracks, but if you're bound by the CPU, you're bound by the CPU.  The only real way to handle heavy CPU load is to offload it to another processor.  Though I suspect for your case you're not actually CPU bound.

Answer (score 0):

i find async perfect for server-side short work - but if you want something much lighter and can deal with less polish you can adapt one of these: http://book.mixu.net/ch7.html

a lot faster from my experience...which is important when running on low-power embedded devices or low-end servers